# jenkins build script cant git pull from remote repo

Tags: jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

> Started by user sabari k
>   Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/actualdairy
>   [actualdairy] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins4465259595371700187.sh
>   + echo hello
>   + cd
>   + ./actualDairy/deploy.sh
>   Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>   Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64)

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
- Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
- Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Thu Oct 25 20:05:25 UTC 2018

  System load:  0.09              Processes:           90
  Usage of /:   8.7% of 24.06GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 38%               IP address for eth0: 
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for eth1:

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
  http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

43 packages can be updated.
6 updates are security updates.

---

Welcome to DigitalOcean's One-Click Node.js Droplet.
To keep this Droplet secure, the UFW firewall is enabled. 
All ports are BLOCKED except 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP), and 443 (HTTPS).

To get started, visit http://do.co/node1804

---

To delete this message of the day: rm -rf /etc/update-motd.d/99-one-click
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

**git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).**

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
Use --update-env to update environment variables
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [all](ids: 0)
[PM2] www ✓
┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem      │ user │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────┼──────────┤
│ www      │ 0  │ 0.0.2   │ fork │ 23688 │ online │ 65      │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 5.4 MB   │ root │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Finished: SUCCESS

i dont know why the git pull is not working. my deploy script is

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@ipaddress <<EOF
cd actualdairy
git pull
npm install
pm2 restart all
exit
EOF
```

i added remote server public key in bitbucket but its not pulling from the repo.saying Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: If you add `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` before `git pull`, then it should show the verbose output of the attempted pull. You might be hitting a network issue, or the key may not be available in a non-interactive shell in the same way that it is in an interactive shell, or there might be something else happening.

Comment: @JimRedmond thank you .i will check that

Comment: @JimRedmond i tried.but no verbose output found.

Comment: Does this machine has permissions to sync from remote repo ? did you added ssh key as access key in remote repo ?

Comment: @ReddysekharGaduputi its worked i had the wrong permission to .ssh folder.deleted the folder and created it now its working.